# This toy is what I know it is. / This toy the thing which I know it is

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses

I want to know the following sentences are possible.

[Context]

My mother is going to give a present for me. And I know what it is. It is a toy.
In that case, can I say something as below?

> This toy is what I know it is.
>
> This toy is the thing which I know it is.

Comment: No. Neither of those is idiomatic.  I might say, “I know what you got me.”  Or “I know you got me a toy”  But the smart thing to do is act surprised and delighted when she gives it to you.

Comment: Hi,@Jim
This toy is what I know it is. / This toy the thing which I know it is, are they wrong by themselves?

Comment: Those sentences are very convoluted.

Comment: Side note: as written, the mother is giving the toy on behalf of the speaker, not to the speaker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the phrasing in the question, this may not be your first language. Neither of the two options provided make complete sense, and sound a little odd. You could say: "I know what the present is; it is a toy" or "I know the present is a toy" or "The present is a toy and I know it" I'm not really getting what concept you're trying for.

Comment: Hi, 
This toy is what I know it is. / This toy the thing which I know it is, are they wrong by itself?

Comment: If you are trying to say that you already know what the present is, they don't make sense.  You would begin a sentence with "This toy..." if you were looking at it or showing it to someone else. Jacob's suggestions are much more natural.